# Can human spinal reflexes make use of a proprioceptive input?

Tags: reflexes, balance

I was out in the car when I wondered why manufacturers place pedal controls crucial for reaction time so very far from the motor cortex.  Is there anything a spinal reflex could work with, which would not be available to the brain in the same time frame?  So I looked this up and found two recent papers:

- [Picton, 2021](https://www.cell.com/neuron/fulltext/S0896-6273(21)00040-4), describing sensation of lateral motion by Piezo2-expressing mechanosensative neurons.
- [Stanchak, 2022](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9480875/), describing mechanosensation in the lumbosacrol organ of birds by neurons expressing myo7a and espin.

The second paper goes so far as to suggest "spinal cords across vertebrates are capable of mechanosensation and that spinal mechanosensory networks have evolved to allow unique functions"

Speaking of function:  **is there any functional evidence that proprioception could directly inform a (learned) spinal reflex in humans?**  Such as a human changing the pressure on a gas or brake pedal in response to acceleration or deceleration, without needing to consult the cerebrum first.  (Any other mammal would also be relevant, but it ought to be easiest to do this sort of experiment with humans)

---

There's been quite a bit of sidetracking about whether reflexes could be involved in driving, so I feel like I should illustrate with a common scenario.  You're coming toward stopped cars at a traffic light, braking fairly heavily, while you've turned your head to one side to look at traffic.  At one point a piece of gravel shifts under the car wheel and you momentarily stop decelerating, so you respond by braking more heavily.  This might be the result of processing a lateral motion at the inner ear, using the cerebellum to compensate for head position and directing a new program of action at the motor cortex; but perhaps it might also involve a direct spinal response to proprioceptive input originating near the sacrum to maintain the intended degree of sensation of deceleration.

Comment: What is "functional evidence"? Also, out of curiosity, did you do a Google Scholar search on, say, "Can spinal reflexes be learned?" It seems to me that the paper you quoted does suggest(?)/state(?) that.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm not quite sure what you're getting at.  As you suggest, such a search does readily find [articles](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/jn.00006.2010) about learning in spinal reflexes. In this case an unlearned reflex would also be satisfactory, but I doubt we can name one involving proprioception since its role is (at best) not well established.

Comment: @anongoodnurse  For "functional evidence" I was imagining some clever experiment might prove quite a bit simply with reaction time.  Maybe if you jerk a person's seat backward in the lab unexpectedly, and they respond by increasing pressure to a simulated gas pedal?  But I can't say how you would *prove* this isn't the result of a stretch reflex, crossed extensor reflex etc.  The same problems apply even more so in the case of tripping, which all the reflexes are designed to prevent.  Still, just because I don't have an idea right off doesn't mean no one has ever come up with one!

Comment: Did you know that pedals on cars used to be purely mechanical? If you're rolling down a hill in a wagon, would you rather brake yourself with your foot or your pinky finger?

Comment: And I am confused here too; the reason driving involves cerebral actions is much because reflexes can be as dangerous as long reaction times (due to alcohol for instance). If I'm on the highway with a lot of cars around me and suddenly I see an animal on my lane, my reflex would be to smash the breakes and save the critters a$$, at a second thought, I think of the fact I'm cruising at 100 km/h with a fender bender on my tail -- now would a reflex have helped you, or resulted in a pile-up instead?...

Comment: ...I understand the question, but I think you should frame it in a different way, because in its current state the driving scenario distracts folks from your real question.

Comment: @AliceD For analogy, consider the role of the quadriceps stretch reflex.  Striking your patella with a rubber mallet seems like a poor contribution to driving, yet you use the same reflex moment-to-moment to help make sure your leg is in the position you think it is on the pedal.  Higher level processing modifies the reflexes, so you can bend your leg to different positions without being defeated by a reflex action and without losing its benefit in the new position.

Comment: @MikeSerfas - I'm more confused now. You can't "override" a spinal reflex, but it is possible over time to modify it some. (Also, nit-picking, but you don't elicit a reflex by hitting the patella, except for maybe the "WTF?" reflex with a grimace of pain. You strike (gently) the *patellar tendon*.) An example of setting off a spinal reflex is touching a hot iron. You can with repeated effort put your hand on the iron and leave it there, but it isn't activated by other activities. Not every stretched muscle twitches, or we wouldn't be able to walk. It's not a matter of cortical overriding. ...

Comment: ... IOW, your cortex isn't modifying how your leg responds to proprioception; you're simply using your leg muscles differently, and appropriately so, to achieve the same effect. You *can* learn (cortical) to fall flat on your face without protecting it, overriding a reflex, but that takes time and effort. Also, it's not very helpful to health or longevity. I'm not a neurologist or neuroscientist, so I don't understand the question as @AliceD seems to. The paper in the link you provided (as well as others) answers in the affirmative. What else are you asking?

Comment: @BryanKrause - I agree you would use one of your strongest muscles to stop a car. With hydraulic brakes on 4 wheels, a pinky would work as well if not as instinctively initially. (Instinctively as in, resisting a forward force, you'd use your legs instinctively.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse My point is that OP's question is based on a false premise; they're thinking that someone designed a car thinking a leg muscle would be a fast way to respond to things. In reality, cars are designed that way because once upon a time someone needed to actually transmit force through the pedals.

Comment: @BryanKrause - Understood. The whole question/premise is questionable imo. The reaction time difference between arms and legs based on their distance from the cerebral cortex is questionable when discussing a spinal reflex. What fraction of a second difference does arm length vs leg length make? I never noticed any lag in reaction time between the biceps and knee reflexes.

Comment: The intercept of 182 ms is an estimate of the time needed for internal processing and response generation; the slope of 45 ms/m for distance; (22 m/s)... So it's 45ms difference between hand/foot. Unlikely is that the number of muscles involved in coordinating the leg and foot to apply brakes, is too complex for mechanosensory response vs a learned reflex which is integrated with learnig logic and the motor cortex. A non-cortex reflex has to also know which of 250 muscles to apply when sensing 100ds of stimuli, i.e. a stone hitting the foot zone under the car.